# Executing certain steps only once the previous step is executed in the same pipeline in apache dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I want to execute a few steps after a few starting steps.
eg: in my case I want to execute starting 3 steps, then last 2 steps.

Once these 3 steps complete execution, then I want to start the last 2 steps.

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p1:
    data_csv = p1 | 'Read CSV file' >> ReadFromText(known_args.input_csv_file)
    dict1 = (data_csv | 'Format to json' >> (beam.ParDo(Split())))
    (dict1 | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                                        known_args.output_stage_bq,
                                        schema=product_revenue_schema
                                        ))
    fullTable = (p1 | 'ReadFromBQ' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(table_spec)))
    (fullTable | 'writeToBQ another dataset' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(known_args.output_target_bq,
                            schema = product_revenue_schema))
```

Expected: 1: Step1 -> step2 -> step3 -> step4 -> step5

Actual: 1: Step1 -> Step2 -> Step3
        2: Step4 -> Step5

Answer (score 3):

In Beam Java SDK, [`Wait`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.12.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Wait.html) transform is what you're looking for.

In Beam Python SDK, there's no such transform available at this moment. You should use two separate pipelines and manually sync them (for example, waiting the first pipeline finishes before launching the second pipeline or sending a pubsub message from the first pipeline to signal the second pipeline that the writing is done).

Comment: Thanks @ihji, one doubt. Does apache beam support creating multiple pipelines in Python?